# Use N type for own macros

Tags: expl3, programming, arguments

**Background**
In LaTeX3 I’m programming some macros to store and read contents from a variable like `\tl_set:Nn` does. An thus I’m generating variants using the `N` type, which causes a warning. The warning suggests to use `V` instead wich would be comprehensible for the *reading* macro `\tobiw_use_thing` but feels wrong for the *writing* macro `\tobiw_save_thing`. Since the manual says (highlighting by me):

> The V and v specifiers are used to **get** the content of a variable […]

**MWE**

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{xparse}

\ExplSyntaxOn

\cs_new:Nn \tobiw_save_thing:nn {
   \tl_set:Nn #1 { #2 }
}
\cs_generate_variant:Nn \tobiw_save_thing:nn { Nn }

\cs_new:Nn \tobiw_use_thing:n {
   \tl_use:N #1
}
\cs_generate_variant:Nn \tobiw_use_thing:n { N }

\NewDocumentCommand{\saveanduse}{ m }{
   \tobiw_save_thing:Nn \l_tmpa_tl { #1 }
   \fbox { \tobiw_use_thing:N \l_tmpa_tl }
}

\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}
   Test
   \saveanduse{Tokens}
\end{document}
```

**Question**
So what is the best approach to create macros like this? What argument types should be used here?

Comment: It should be `\cs_new_protected:Nn \tobiw_save_things:Nn` to begin with. No variant needed.

Comment: Why aren't you directly generating functions like `\tobiw_save_thing:Nn`? You would not get any warning.

Comment: Btw: Conversion n to N is not well-formed, it should be n to V, but on the other hand there are the equivalents c and N if you want to be able to consume a group as csname.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You *must not* use variants here.

Variants are needed when a basic function, with signature consisting only of `N` or `n` specifiers (or in inclusive sense, to be clear), needs some kind of expansion of arguments before it takes action:

- `V` is a variant for `n`, where the variant function will receive a single token (which should be the name of a suitable variable) and the basic function will receive as its `n` argument the value.
- `f` and `x` are variants for `n`, where the contents of the braces will be `f`- or `x`-expanded.
- `o` is a variant for `n`, where the contents of the braces will be “one time expanded”, in the sense that the first token in the list will be expanded once.
- `c` is a variant for `N`, where the contents of the braces will be transformed in a single token to be fed as the `N` argument.

You are defining two basic functions and both expect a single token as their first (or unique) argument: this asks for an argument of type `N`.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{xparse}

\ExplSyntaxOn

\cs_new_protected:Nn \tobiw_save_thing:Nn
 {
   \tl_set:Nn #1 { #2 }
 }

\cs_new:Nn \tobiw_use_thing:N
 {
   \tl_use:N #1
 }

\NewDocumentCommand{\saveanduse}{ m }
 {
   \tobiw_save_thing:Nn \l_tmpa_tl { #1 }
   \fbox { \tobiw_use_thing:N \l_tmpa_tl }
 }

\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}
   Test
   \saveanduse{Tokens}
\end{document}
```

Note that the first function should be defined with `_protected`, because it *sets* some variable.

The function defining facilities `\cs_new_...` or `\cs_set_...` have basic signatures `:Nn` or `:Npn`. The signature of the defined function should only consist of strings of `N` or `n` (inclusive sense); `w` is only allowed in the `:Npn` case.

As an example, you have `\tobiw_use_thing:N`, but you possibly want

```
\cs_new:Nn \tobiw_use_thing:n
 {
  Do something with #1
 }
\cs_generate_variant:Nn \tobiw_use_thing:n { V }
```

allowing calls such as

```
\tobiw_use_thing:n {whatever}
```

or

```
\tobiw_use_thing:V \l_tmpa_tl
```

But, at the end, it depends on what your functions are supposed to do.

Comment: Thanks! … sometimes its quite easy … didn’t saw this solution. In this case would you recommend to use `\tobiw_use_thing:N` or `\tobiw_use_thing:V`?

Comment: @Tobi It depends on what you want the function to do. I'll add something.

Comment: I see. So `N` when I’m sure that there is always a single token and `n`+`V` when there are multiple tokes directly given as argument or as a variable content, right?

Comment: @Tobi Yes, that's the idea.

Answer (score 4):

You do not need any variant here, you could simply define functions with `N` type arguments. If your main concern is to allow also grouped input (as csname) generate a `c` variant afterwards.

Your functions uses the specifier `n` which stands for a group of tokens. You can convert those (as variant) to `V` type arguments, because that way the idea of getting a group of tokens stays intact. On the other hand you have the pair of `c` and `N`, where the former accepts a group of tokens (but forms one control word out of it) and the latter accepts one token, a control word.

When designing functions you should design with the purpose of the argument in mind. If you want a control sequence as argument use one of `N` or `c`. If you want some value use `n`, `o`, `x`, `f`, `V` or `v`.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{xparse}

\ExplSyntaxOn

\cs_new:Nn \tobiw_save_thing:Nn {
   \tl_set:Nn #1 { #2 }
}
\cs_generate_variant:Nn \tobiw_save_thing:Nn { cn }

\cs_new:Nn \tobiw_use_thing:N {
   \tl_use:N #1
}
\cs_generate_variant:Nn \tobiw_use_thing:N { c }

\NewDocumentCommand{\saveanduse}{ m }{
   \tobiw_save_thing:Nn \l_tmpa_tl { #1 }
   \fbox { \tobiw_use_thing:N \l_tmpa_tl }
}

\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}
   Test
   \saveanduse{Tokens}
\end{document}
```